# Creating clusters of related columns

Tags: t-sql

I have a table named `Stores` with columns:

```
StoreCode    NVARCHAR(10),
OldStoreCode NVARCHAR(10)
```

Here is a sample of my data:

```
| StoreCode | OldStoreCode |
|-----------|--------------|
| A         | B            |
| B         | A            |
| D         | E            |
| E         | F            |
| M         | K            |
| J         | K            |
| K         | L            |
|-----------|--------------|
```

I want to create clusters of related `Stores`. Related store means there is a one way relation between `StoreCodes` and `OldStoreCodes`.

Expected result table:

```
| StoreCode | ClusterId |
|-----------|-----------|
| A         | 1         |
| B         | 1         |
| D         | 2         |
| E         | 2         |
| F         | 2         |
| M         | 3         |
| K         | 3         |
| J         | 3         |
| L         | 3         |
|-----------|-----------|
```

There is no maximum number hops. There may be a `StoreCode A` which has a `OldStoreCode B`, which has a `OldStoreCode C`, which has a `OldStoreCode D` etc.

How can I cluster stores like this?

Comment: Can you show your expected result

Comment: Please explain the logic of *related store*. I have no idea what you need...

Comment: From the examples it looks like you are relating Store to OldStore, but then relating any OldStore to another Old Store (M->K, K->L relates M to L). Are you certain that is the intention?

Comment: @Shnugo
Two stores are related if one of them in StoreCode column and another in OldStoreCode column, in a record

Comment: @Anthony
I've intentionally give the situation as an example. Given that relations M->K, J->K, K->L  I need to say stores M,K,J,L forms a cluster.

Comment: @TheGameiswar
The second table in the question is the result table I expected.

Comment: Starting to understand... The given sample has closed islands. What if there is a cross-cluster relationship? One big cluster?

Comment: Have you tried looking into using recursive queries to solve your problem?

Comment: @Shnugo If any two stores are related, they should be already in the same cluster in result table. So, there shouldn't be any cross-cluster relationship.

Comment: @Anthony I haven't tried recursive queries yet but I will be looking into them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try it like this:

### EDIT: With changes by OP taken from comment

```
DECLARE @tbl TABLE(ID INT IDENTITY, StoreCode VARCHAR(100),OldStoreCode VARCHAR(100));
INSERT INTO @tbl VALUES
 ('A','B'),('B','A'),('D','E'),('E','F'),('M','K'),('J','K'),('K','L');

WITH Related AS
(
    SELECT DISTINCT t1.ID,Val
    FROM @tbl AS t1
    INNER JOIN @tbl AS t2 ON t1.StoreCode=t2.StoreCode 
                          OR t1.OldStoreCode=t2.OldStoreCode 
                          OR t1.OldStoreCode=t2.StoreCode 
                          OR t1.StoreCode=t2.OldStoreCode
    CROSS APPLY(SELECT DISTINCT Val
                FROM
                (VALUES(t1.StoreCode),(t2.StoreCode),(t1.OldStoreCode),(t2.OldStoreCode)) AS A(Val)
               ) AS valsInCols
)
,ClusterKeys AS
(
    SELECT r1.ID
          ,(
            SELECT r2.Val AS [*] 
            FROM Related AS r2
            WHERE r2.ID=r1.ID
            ORDER BY r2.Val
            FOR XML PATH('')
           ) AS ClusterKey
    FROM Related AS r1
    GROUP BY r1.ID
)
,ClusterIds AS 
( 
    SELECT ClusterKey
          ,MIN(ID) AS ID 
    FROM ClusterKeys 
    GROUP BY ClusterKey 
) 
SELECT r.ID
     ,r.Val 
FROM ClusterIds c 
INNER JOIN Related r ON c.ID = r.ID
```

The result

```
ID  Val
1   A
1   B
3   D
3   E
3   F
5   J
5   K
5   L
5   M
```

Comment: I've made following additions to your solution and I've reached the expected result.

Comment: I've made following additions to your solution and I've reached the expected result.

Comment: @ekremsekerci, sorry, don't see your *additions*... Glad to read, that this works for you. It was nice to tick the acceptance check, if the issue is solved. Happy Coding!

Comment: I've made following additions to your solution and I've reached the expected result.

Making your result table a CTE named ClusterKeys:

ClusterIds AS 
(
SELECT 
    ClusterKey,
    MIN(ID) AS ID
FROM
    ClusterKeys
Group by 
    ClusterKey
)

SELECT 
    r.ID,
    r.Val
FROM
    ClusterIds c 
    INNER JOIN #Related r
    ON c.ID = r.ID

Comment: @ekremsekerci, yes, one more CTE will allow you to work with the derived table easily.

Comment: thanks for your help. I'm having problems with usage comments, because I'm new. Is it appropriate to give the full solution as a separate answer? Or should I edit your answer and accept it?

Comment: @ekremsekerci I edited your addition into my answer. If this is correct, please tick the acceptance check. Once you've crossed the 15 rep points yourself you are invited to come back and vote on it additionally... :-)

Answer (score 0):

This should do it:

SAMPLE DATA:

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#Temp1') IS NOT NULL
    BEGIN
       DROP TABLE #Temp1;
    END;

CREATE TABLE #Temp1(StoreCode    NVARCHAR(10)
               , OldStoreCode NVARCHAR(10));

INSERT INTO       #Temp1(StoreCode
                   , OldStoreCode)
VALUES
      ('A'
     , 'B'),
      ('B'
     , 'A'),
      ('D'
     , 'E'),
      ('E'
     , 'F'),
      ('M'
     , 'K'),
      ('J'
     , 'K'),
      ('K'
     , 'L');
```

QUERY:

```
;WITH A -- get all distinct new and old storecodes
    AS (
    SELECT StoreCode
    FROM     #Temp1
    UNION
    SELECT OldStoreCode
    FROM   #Temp1),
    B -- give a unique number id to each store code
    AS (SELECT rn = RANK() OVER(ORDER BY StoreCode)
            , StoreCode
        FROM   A),
    C -- combine the store codes and the unique number id's  in one table
    AS (SELECT b2.rn AS StoreCodeID
            , t.StoreCode
            , b1.rn AS OldStoreCodeId
            , t.OldStoreCode
        FROM   #Temp1 AS t
             LEFT OUTER JOIN B AS b1 ON t.OldStoreCode = b1.StoreCode
             LEFT OUTER JOIN B AS b2 ON t.StoreCode = b2.StoreCode),
    D -- assign a row number for each entry in the data set
    AS (SELECT rn = RANK() OVER(ORDER BY StoreCode)
            , *
        FROM   C),
    E -- derive first and last store in the path
    AS (SELECT FirstStore = d2.StoreCode
            , LastStore = d1.OldStoreCode
            , GroupID = d1.OldStoreCodeId
        FROM   D AS d1
             RIGHT OUTER JOIN D AS d2 ON d1.StoreCodeID = d2.OldStoreCodeId
                                    AND d1.rn - 1 = d2.rn
        WHERE  d1.OldStoreCode IS NOT NULL) ,
    F -- get the stores wich led to the last store with one hop
    AS  (SELECT C.StoreCode
            , E.GroupID
        FROM   E
             INNER JOIN C ON E.LastStore = C.OldStoreCode)

     -- combine to get the full grouping
     SELECT A.StoreCode, ClusterID = DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY A.GroupID)  FROM (
    SELECT C.StoreCode,F.GroupID FROM C INNER JOIN F ON C.OldStoreCode = F.StoreCode 
    UNION 
    SELECT * FROM F
    UNION 
    SELECT E.LastStore,E.GroupID FROM E) AS A ORDER BY StoreCode, ClusterID
```

RESULTS:

[image]

Comment: could you please be more constructive as why the down vote so I can improve?

Comment: Hi, I did not downvote this, and have no idea why... +1 from my side